# I can't manage to do the code for a repetitive letter in a guessword game in netbeans jframe

Tags: java, netbeans

Can anyone help me by telling me what's the problem with my whileloop code? Why isn't the letter "l" from "hello" shown in the word on the next position? How do I have to change what I have?

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author w1567187
 */
public class GuessForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
String FindWord = "hello";

/**
 * Creates new form GuessForm
 */
public GuessForm() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    char0 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    char1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    char2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    char3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    char4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    char5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tryLetter = new javax.swing.JButton();
    aLetter = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    inCorrect = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    MyMessage = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    imageOfHangman = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    char0.setText("X");

    char1.setText("X");

    char2.setText("X");

    char3.setText("X");

    char4.setText("X");

    char5.setText("X");

    tryLetter.setText("Try Letter");
    tryLetter.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tryLetterActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    aLetter.setText("e");

    inCorrect.setText("0");

    MyMessage.setText("Look here..");

    imageOfHangman.setText("jButton1");
    imageOfHangman.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            imageOfHangmanActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(MyMessage)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(inCorrect)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                    .addComponent(aLetter)
                                    .addComponent(tryLetter, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(223, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(char0)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(char1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(char2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(char3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(char4)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(char5)
                    .addGap(213, 213, 213)))
            .addComponent(imageOfHangman, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 637, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                    .addComponent(tryLetter)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(aLetter, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(inCorrect)
                    .addGap(203, 203, 203)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(char0)
                        .addComponent(char1)
                        .addComponent(char2)
                        .addComponent(char3)
                        .addComponent(char4)
                        .addComponent(char5))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(MyMessage))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(imageOfHangman, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 637, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void tryLetterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_tryLetterActionPerformed

int dd=Integer.parseInt(inCorrect.getText());             
String letter=aLetter.getText();
int charPos=FindWord.indexOf(letter);
MyMessage.setText("Position is"+ charPos);

if (charPos==-1) {                     
    dd=dd+1;        
    String ss=Integer.toString(dd);
    inCorrect.setText(ss);        
        if (dd == 1)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\1.png"));            
        if (dd == 2)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\2.png"));            
        if (dd == 3)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\3.png"));            
        if (dd == 4)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\4.png"));            
        if (dd == 5)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\5.png"));            
        if (dd == 6)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\6.png"));            
        if (dd == 7)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\7.png"));            
        if (dd == 8)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\8.png"));            
        if (dd == 9)  imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\9.png"));            
        if (dd == 10) imageOfHangman.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\w1567187\\Desktop\\10.png"));            
        if (dd > 10)  MyMessage.setText("Game Over");    
}
else{
    if (charPos == 0)  char0.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 1)  char1.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 2)  char2.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 3)  char3.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 4)  char4.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 5)  char5.setText(letter);
}



   while (charPos >= 0) {
      charPos = FindWord.indexOf(letter, charPos + 1); 

    if (charPos == 0)  char0.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 1)  char1.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 2)  char2.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 3)  char3.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 4)  char4.setText(letter);        
    if (charPos == 5)  char5.setText(letter);
   }         
   //GEN-LAST:event_tryLetterActionPerformed
}




private void imageOfHangmanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_imageOfHangmanActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_imageOfHangmanActionPerformed

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GuessForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GuessForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GuessForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GuessForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GuessForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JLabel MyMessage;
private javax.swing.JTextField aLetter;
private javax.swing.JLabel char0;
private javax.swing.JLabel char1;
private javax.swing.JLabel char2;
private javax.swing.JLabel char3;
private javax.swing.JLabel char4;
private javax.swing.JLabel char5;
private javax.swing.JButton imageOfHangman;
private javax.swing.JLabel inCorrect;
private javax.swing.JButton tryLetter;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

}

Comment: for all your `if`s you should probably use `if..else` or `switch...case`

Comment: No, it is not that. still not working. Concretely, do u know if the while loop is wrong?

Comment: without all of your code I can't say for certain